# In Bittorrent how to announce utp port for other peers

Tags: p2p, bittorrent, dht, torrent

I'm developing a torrent client in Dart, but while implementing utp socket I see no way to announce the utp port
looking at the specifications of the main peer discovery mechanisms [bep0003](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) [bep0005](https://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0005.html) I see that they both talk about announcing the tcp port and no talk about announcing the utp port.

Is there some specification/extension to announce to tracker/dht that my port is utp and not tcp? or should peer try to connect to the port using tcp and then try utp if it fails to connect?

Answer (score 0):

It's assumed that the TCP and UDP port numbers are the same.

Comment: Is there an official source for this statement? Also what is the expected algorithm for connecting? Should the client try utp then tcp? or TCP then utp? or connect to both? or is it up to the implementor to decide?

Comment: No source, but the requirement arises naturally from the peer discovery protocols lacking a way to distinguish the protocols. The order isn't specified and left to the implementation.